# Does OpenSSL library 3.0.8 support Cipher suite whose prefix start with ECDH,such as (ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA, ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 )

Tags: encryption, openssl

Our program originally usd OpenSSL library 1.0.2 and support cipher suite whose prefix start with ECDH, such as:

ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHAECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA

Recently we upgrade the depent OpenSSL library to 3.0, we found use such cipher suites can't talk with server successfully.

From the OpenSSL 3.0 document, https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-ciphers.html, we found the supported cipher list doesn't contain above cipher suites, does that mean In the OpenSSL 3.0, it won't support such cipher suite anymore?

I use the comand openssl ciphers -v -provider default ALL, openssl ciphers -v -provider legacy ALL, all the output result doesn't contain such cipher suite, does that mean the cipher suite realted code has removed from the OpenSSL repo Or Does the OpenSSL library has some config option or build option to support such cipher suites?

Currently I have tested ECDHE realted cipher suite, all these cipher suite talk with server successfully.

I have use OpenSSL 1.0.2 client(supported above cipher suite) talk with the OpenSSL 3.0 server, they can't talk with the server successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**.

The static-ECDH suites were partly implemented in late 0.9.x and fully in 1.0.0-2, although the ones that use GCM (or other AEAD) or SHA-2 are specific to TLS1.2 and thus only work in 1.0.1-2. In contrast, static-DH (now called static-FFDH to avoid ambiguity) suites were not implemented originally, and *added* in 1.0.2. However 1.1.0 and up (i.e. after SMACK and also Heartbleed) entirely replaced the accreted-over-time handshake logic with a new more rigorous one, and in the process it *removed* the implementations of both static-ECDH and static-FFDH. It also removed the export suites and the code for SSLv2 which is no longer even buildable, in contrast to SSLv3 which in 1.1.0 up is disabled by default (that was also the first feature-change version after POODLE) but can still be enabled if you really want.

Plus, of course, 1.1.1 up implemented TLS1.3, and TLS1.3 doesn't have the keyexchange in the ciphersuite (at all) and doesn't allow any static-[FF|EC]DH keyexchange ever.

Do you really have ECC cert(s) that isn't(aren't) signature-capable? Those are *very very* rare, like I think you may be the only one in the world to do so. If you have signature-capable ECC cert(s) just use it(them) for ECDHE-ECDSA in 1.2 (or below, but that's not recommended), and ECDSA authentication (with any supported KX) in 1.3.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, from the news of OpenSSL https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NEWS.md#openssl-102, it says
"All of the low-level DH, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA and RSA public key functions have been deprecated.", does this sentence mean the ECDH cipher suites related code has been removed?

Comment: That has nothing to do with SSL/TLS ciphersuites. libcrypto for decades had two 'levels' of calling crypto _primitives_  (ciphers, hashes, signatures, etc): a direct per-algorithm 'low-level' interface and a 'high-level' generic 'envelope' interface, which among other things makes it easier to change algorithms when needed. The high-level interface was always recommended, but starting in the mid-2010s (part of 1.0.x and all of 1.1.x) the low-level interfaces were actively deprecated, and most of them changed to make the C types 'opaque' so your code couldn't directly manipulate them.

Comment: Note there is only one ECDH _algorithm_ or _primitive_; ECDHE (ephemeral) and ECDH_anon (AECDH in OpenSSL notation) versus static-ECDH are different _ways of using_ that same algorithm in keyexchange protocols which in turn are used in ciphersuites. Similarly there is one [FF]]DH which can be used as DHE or DH_anon/ADH.

Comment: thanks dave, still have one more question, in the answer says, " 1.1.0 and up (i.e. after SMACK and also Heartbleed) entirely replaced the accreted-over-time handshake logic with a new more rigorous one, and in the process it removed the implementations of both static-ECDH and static-FFDH." I read a lot about the OpenSSL news github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NEWS.md, but I didn't find information about that change, could you help give me some keywords about this change?

Comment: From the page you cite: "SSL/TLS state machine, version negotiation and record layer rewritten" (in 1.1.0)